# Update document in a JSON Collection using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, json

I would like to update document in a JSON Collection using AngularJS

My JSON Collection:

```
$Scope.employee = {
        "staff" : 
        [
            {
              "id" : 1,
              "Name" : "John",
              "email" : "john@abc.com"
            },
            {
              "id" : 2,
              "Name" : "Watson",
              "email" : "watson@abc.com"
            },
            {
              "id" : 3,
              "Name" : "jack",
              "email" : "jack@abc.com"
            },
            {
              "id" : 4,
              "Name" : "Jim",
              "email" : "jim@abc.com"
            },
            {
              "id" : 5,
              "Name" : "Rose",
              "email" : "rose@abc.com"
            }
        ]            
  };
```

Now I need to update the document where **`Id = 2`** to

```
$Scope.updateEmployee = {
    "id" : 2,
    "Name": "Emma",
    "email": "emma@abc.com"
};
```

Kindly assist me how to replace a particular document and I would like to update the **`email`** of **`id = 5`** to **`hr@abc.com`**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this,

```
$scope.update = function(){
 $scope.employee.staff.forEach(function (item) {
    if (item.id == 2 ) {
        item.Name = "Emma";
        item.email ="emma@abc.com";
    };        
});     
}
```

[`DEMO`](http://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/qpehzc20/6/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.updateItem = function(item) {
  for (var i = 0; i < $cope.employee.staff.length; i++) {
    if (item.id === $scope.employee.staff[i].id) {
      $scope.employee.staff[i] = item;
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Now if you want to update $Scope.employee with id 5, just do :

```
$scope.updateItem({
  id: 5,
  Name: 'bill',
  email: 'test@test.fr'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/)

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/j72yeY0kLXPtSZRX3mOv?p=options)

Basically, you should refrain from traversing your entire list because this can cause some performance related issues. What `underscore.js` will do is that it will return as soon as it finds an acceptable element, and doesn't traverse the entire list.

Read the official documentation [here](http://underscorejs.org/#find)

> **find_.find(list, predicate, [context])** *Alias: detect*
>   Looks through each value in the list, returning the first one that passes a 
>   truth test (predicate), or undefined if no value passes the test. The
>   function returns as soon as it finds an acceptable element, and
>   doesn't traverse the entire list.

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.employee = {
        "staff": [{
            "id": 1,
            "Name": "John",
            "email": "john@abc.com"
        }, {
            "id": 2,
            "Name": "Watson",
            "email": "watson@abc.com"
        }, {
            "id": 3,
            "Name": "jack",
            "email": "jack@abc.com"
        }, {
            "id": 4,
            "Name": "Jim",
            "email": "jim@abc.com"
        }, {
            "id": 5,
            "Name": "Rose",
            "email": "rose@abc.com"
        }]
    };
    $scope.update = function() {
        var index = _.findIndex($scope.employee.staff, function(o) {
            return o.id == 2;
        })
        $scope.employee.staff[index].Name = "Emma";
        $scope.employee.staff[index].email = "emma@abc.com";
    }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <script>document.write('
   <base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.9/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="emp in employee.staff ">
   <div>{{emp.id}} {{emp.Name}}</div>
  </div>
  <button ng-click="update()">
     Update
    </button>
 </body>
</html>
```